# SSL certificate imported on Glassfish Server, but the browser is showong error for https URL

Tags: ssl, https, glassfish

I have followed these two sites for SSL setup on my glassfish server.
https://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/
and
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4495/ghlgv/index.html

Https with default s1as was working fine. Then I followed these steps

1. Deleted existing s1as from keystore.jks and cacerts.jks.
2. Generated alias (tried SOME_OTHER_ALIAS or, s1as)
3. Exported it
4. Imported it to truststore cacerts.jks
5. Restarted the server.
6. Then typed the URL in browser. https://localhost:8181/HelloWorld
7. I got a blank page saying "This webpage is not available", "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".
8. Checked server.log file inside C:\Program Files\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs. But, no error was there.

System details are as follows,

1. Glassfish Version: Glassfish3.1.2-Windows
2. Master Password of Glassfish: changeit
3. Keypass: changeit
4. Storepass: changeit

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unknowingly, I was putting some random name for the First and Last Name (CN) of SSL key. It must be the the domain name or IP address of the server.